# How can I filter messages based on their Received: headers?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange-2010

On my Exchange account, I'm getting spam mail with forged, valid `From:` addresses (e.g. my own).
The forging can be told by the `Received:` headers.

How can I define a filter based on the contents of the `Received:` headers?
I'm using Outlook 2010 and Exchange 2010. (No, I can't do anything about the Exchange server.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can. However you can filter based on specified words in the Message Header. You just can't narrow the search to the `Received:` header specifically. If the forge-signature that you are searching for is specific enough, that may get you what you need.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'the Message Header', all headers collectively?

Comment: yes; http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/view-e-mail-message-headers-HA001230300.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I found the option in the Rules Wizard, but I do not see how to use this to filter out messages whose From header is in a particular domain, while the Received headers indicate it was sent from elsewhere. So your answer is helpful but I'm still hoping for a definite 'yes' or 'no'.

Comment: ah, now I understand better what you are trying to accomplish: you're looking for a mismatch between the From: domain and the Received: domain. I'm afraid you won't be able to do that from within an Outlook filter. I would think that anti-phishing software on the Exchange server should be able to do this readily. Perhaps yours needs an upgrade?

Comment: As I said, the Exchange server is not under my control. Generally it's (i.e. its sysadmins are) pretty much perfect at weeding out spam; I just want to know what additional things I can do myself.

Comment: I would address your specific concerns to them.